# Hello...does the website layout must be flex or float in order to apply @media?

Tags: css, media-queries

I just want to apply @media for mobile with these sizes: smaller than 400px,between 401px and 750px, larger than 750px.But its not working..so i think is because there is not flex or float layout.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Please share your code, something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is no connection between media queries and flexbox/float.

Make sure you have the proper **viewport** tag within the **head** section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```